# Ruby on Rails: How to do a spec test for a policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.3.1

I'm trying to create a spec test for a policy, which is called in my situation base_policy. I need to test if the policies are respected.

My base_policy:

```
class Study::BasePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def default?
    @user.has_edit_access?
  end

  def  terminology_toggle?
    @user.has_edit_access?
  end
end
```

I tried to do the spec but is not working good and giving errors as

```
Study::BasePolicy for read access allows access
     Failure/Error: let (:base) {Base.new}

   NameError:
       uninitialized constant Base
```

My spec file as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Study::BasePolicy do
  include UserAccountHelpers
  include PermissionsHelpers

  subject {described_class.new(user, base)}
  let (:base) {Base.new}

  before :each do
    ua_create
  end

  after :each do
    ua_destroy
  end

  context "for read access" do
    let (:user) {@user_r}

    it "allows access" do
      allow_list [:detail]
    end

    it "deny access" do
      deny_list [:edit, :update, :default, :terminology_toggle]
    end
  end

  context "for edit access" do
    let (:user) {@user_e}

    it "allows access" do
      allow_list [:edit, :update, :default, :terminology_toggle]
    end
  end

  context "for system admin access" do
    let (:user) {@user_sa}

    it "allows access" do
      allow_list [:edit, :update, :default, :terminology_toggle]
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to understand a good way to test this policy as my knowledge in the testing in rails is limited.

Comment: Is there actually a class called `Base`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a class named Base this line won't work

```
  let (:base) {Base.new}
```

You're trying to create an instance of a class that doesn't exist. For example if you have a class `Person` then you could do

```
let(:person) { Person.new }
```

or
 `@person = Person.new` in a before block.

Comment: So I have that policy for base policy, in this case, I should delete that part for class and will work the spec? Or in my case, my spec file is not good for it? Just would like to know some suggestion in case :)

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about the details of what you are testing.  If you haven't take a good look at the docs here https://relishapp.com/rspec.  When I was learning rspec I started by making simple classes and testing class and instance methods until I had a clear grasp of the syntax and structure.